# different htaccess for directory issue

Tags: .htaccess

```
root 
  /question
  /pages
  index.html
  .htaccess
```

**/root/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/question
```

**/question/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^question/are-bitcoin-gains-taxable/?$  /pages/questions/viewQuestion.php?id=9 [L]
```

So what I'm trying to do is separate my htaccess into directories, this current setup is producing /404 error `/pages/questions/viewQuestion.php?` does exist, I just think its not reading the second .htaccess , Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need anything in root .htaccess for this and just a `RewriteCond` by itself isn't doing anything anyway.

You just need to have this rule in `/question/.htaccess`

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^are-bitcoin-gains-taxable/?$ /pages/questions/viewQuestion.php?id=9 [L,NC,QSA]
```

URI paths in `RewriteRule` are relative to the directory where .htaccess is located so `question/` won't be matched here.